# Meaning of Regular expression validator

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Canyou please tell me what the below regular expression represents.

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9_$]$)/i
```

because when using this expression it is returning error if space is there in the value

can any one pls help me how to resolve that error.

This is the function i am using in jquery

```
function RestrictChar(theValue) 
{         
    var regulare = /([a-zA-Z0-9_$]$)/i;
    return regulare.test(theValue);        
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey veena -can i make a comment on the bigger issue here. you're using copy/paste code that you have no understanding of and are therefore in a very vulnerable position. i'd suggest that you always look at the solution to your problem thro garnering a complete vision of what your final code is intended to do, as well as comprehensin of how it does it. this is not a criticism, this is sound advice for you, especially if some poor soul is going to have to support your work - they will hunt you down :).

Comment: Thanks for  your valuable comments

Answer (score 0):

It means that the text must end with any of the following characters in any order and combination and at least one character (basically this can be used as a white list for an input validation):
. letters a to z
. letters A to Z
. numbers 0 to 9
. _
. $

you can include the empty space as follows:

```
 var regulare = /([a-zA-Z0-9_$ ]$)/i;
```

notice the empty space before `]`

Accepted input for `/([a-zA-Z0-9_$ ]$)/i`:
&sss
@#@#k
hello
hi_hi
23k3j4k
lkjs KE
Kkj$s_K334

Unaccepted input:
sskk#
@
&#
kka!

Comment: No, the `$` outside of the character classes represents "the end of the string" in regex

Comment: It makes no difference, the brackets just make it an implicit capture group.

Comment: thanks a lot its working fine 
can you please let me know how to add space in below expressiojns

var zipRegex = /(^[a-zA-Z]{1}\d{5}$)/i;
    var ZipRegex2 = /^\d{5}$/;

Comment: Please check updated answer. The regex is for input that ends with specified characters. Thus, something like `@!!@hello` is accepted

Answer (score 0):

You have to add \s to variable regulare

```
 function RestrictChar(theValue) {
    var regulare = /([a-z\sA-Z0-9_$]$)/i;
    return regulare.test(theValue);
}
```